# In what layer does the logic for choosing a wifi channel reside?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, wifi-driver

Is this logic contained in the driver software, or is it implemented somewhere in the hardware of the network card.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, and you don't specify what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're looking for information on which channel is chosen when connecting to a network, it is chosen by the person that set up the WiFi hardware or the defaults of the hardware.

Comment: The wifi access point (or router) is configured for a channel, the client (or pc) joining the network has no control over the channel used, it must join on the channel that's broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Access Point, The channel is set by user interface(such as some HTML thing), then it will be passed to the driver to set the hardware register, the register will make hardware focus on the channel. In conclusion, the channel is a hardware parameter, but can be set by user.

In the 802.11 hardware, the RF will emit electromagnetic waves to another STA(802.11 station). The receiver will filter these waves and pass the data to the upper layer. The channel setting affects the RF filter.